# Argparse default as function is always called

Tags: python, argparse

//edit 1: Changed slightly `get_variable` - forgot to add another argument that is passed to it (was writing it from memory, sorry for that).

I have a problem with `default` values from `argparser`.

Some values if not present in command line, are taken from environment using `os.env`, *and if there is none, get it from `DEFAULT_FOR_VARIABLE`*:

```
def get_variable(name, DEFAULT_FOR_VARIABLE = ''):
    if name in os.environ:
        return os.environ[name]
    print("no default value")
    return DEFAULT_FOR_VARIABLE
```

This is how it's parsed in `main()`:

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description=MODULE_NAME)
parser.add_argument('--test_arg', default=get_variable(VAR_NAME, DEFAULT_FOR_TEST_ARG))
args = parser.parse_args()
print(args.test_arg)
```

No matter if I pass down arguments or not, `get_variable` function is called and if there is no value in `os.environ`, `print` gets executed (to let me know there is missing argument), even when there is a value passed:

```
λ python Parser_Test.py --test_arg test_arg
no default value
test_arg
```

It's working as expected when arguments are not passed:

```
λ python Parser_Test.py
No default value
```

But when for `DEFAULT_FOR_TEST_ARG` is set:

```
λ python Parser_Test.py
  No default value
  DEFAULT_VALUE_FOR_TEST_ARG
```

Also checking each parsed argument would be hard, since there is no way of iterating them the way it's provided by `argparse` - I have quite few of them to check for from the user.

Is there a way to change this behavior? Or should I use non-standard module for parsing arguments in such a case?

Comment: You have to supply a default *value*, the result of calling the function, so of course the function gets called either way. It's not clear why you expected that would be deferred. You could move this to a post-`parse_args` step easily, though: `if not args.test_arg: ...`.

Comment: So in other words - dont bother with default of add_argument? Got it, thanks for anwser.

Answer (score 3):

`get_variable(VAR_NAME)` is evaluated by the interpreter when the `add_argument` method is used.  In python function arguments are evaluated before being passed to the function.

`argparse` does defer evaluating the default if it is a string:

```
In [271]: p = argparse.ArgumentParser()
In [272]: p.add_argument('-f', type=int, default='12');
In [273]: p.parse_args('-f 23'.split())
Out[273]: Namespace(f=23)
In [274]: p.parse_args([])
Out[274]: Namespace(f=12)
```

Here, if no `-f` is provided, the `'12'` will be passed to the `type` function:

```
int('12')
```

or with a custom `type`:

```
In [275]: def mytype(astr):
     ...:     print('eval',astr)
     ...:     return int(astr)
In [276]: p.add_argument('-g', type=mytype, default='12');
In [277]: p.parse_args([])
eval 12
Out[277]: Namespace(f=12, g=12)
In [278]: p.parse_args(['-g','3'])
eval 3
Out[278]: Namespace(f=12, g=3)
```

But in your case the code that you want to conditionally evaluate probably can't be handled by a `type` function.  That is, you aren't evaluating the default in the same way as you would an user provided string.

So a post parsing test probably makes most sense.  The default default is `None`, which is easily tested:

```
if args.test is None:
     args.test = 'the proper default'
```

The user can't provide any string that will produce `None`, so it is a safe `default`.

---

Just out of curiosity I wrote a `type` that looks up a name in `os.environ`:

```
In [282]: def get_environ(name):
     ...:     if name in os.environ:
     ...:         return os.environ[name]
     ...:     raise argparse.ArgumentTypeError('%s not in environ'%name)

In [283]: p.add_argument('-e', type=get_environ, default='DISPLAY');
```

Without arguments it looks up the default `os.environ['DISPLAY']`

```
In [284]: p.parse_args([])
eval 12
Out[284]: Namespace(e=':0', f=12, g=12)
```

with a valid name:

```
In [289]: p.parse_args(['-e','EDITOR'])
eval 12
Out[289]: Namespace(e='nano', f=12, g=12)
```

and raises an error when the name isn't valid:

```
In [290]: p.parse_args(['-e','FOO'])
usage: ipython3 [-h] [-f F] [-g G] [-e E]
ipython3: error: argument -e: FOO not in environ
An exception has occurred, use %tb to see the full traceback.
```

I know it's not what you are aiming for, but it gives an idea of what is possible if you want to delay evaluation of a default.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if I fully understand, but can you not do this?

```
def get_variable(name):
    if name in os.environ:
        return os.environ[name]
    else:
        print("no default value")
        return 'empty'
```

Or:

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description=MODULE_NAME)
parser.add_argument('--test_arg',dest='test',nargs='?', default="empty")
args = parser.parse_args()
if args.test == "empty":
    if name in os.environ:
        newGlobalVar = os.environ["name"]
        print("no default value")
    else:
        newGlobalVar = args.test
```

Comment: Forgot to add two chunks in get_variable and how its exactly passed in code, will edit in a moment.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an approach using a lambda as the default in python 3.6.  I think this is on target with what the OP wanted to do.  The default doesn't get evaluated immediately.  You can easily find them and call them in a for loop to resolve the values.  I included the t2 argument with a string default just to show that a normal default still works fine in this context.

```
import argparse
import os


def get_value(var, dflt):
    if var in os.environ:
        return os.environ[var]
    return dflt


parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description=os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(__file__))[0])
parser.add_argument('--t1', default=lambda: get_value('t1_value', 't1 default'))
parser.add_argument('--t2', default='t2 default')
args = parser.parse_args()
print("Arguments have been parsed")
print(f"--t1: {args.t1}")
print(f"--t2: {args.t2}")


print("Lazily getting defaults")
for key in vars(args):
    f = args.__dict__[key]
    if callable(f):
        print(f'Getting default value for {key}')
        args.__dict__[key] = f()

print(f"--t1: {args.t1}")
print(f"--t2: {args.t2}")
```

Results:

```
Connected to pydev debugger (build 202.7660.27)
Arguments have been parsed
--t1: <function <lambda> at 0x000002425DD3FAE8>
--t2: t2 default
Lazily getting defaults
Getting default value for t1
--t1: t1_default
--t2: t2 default

Process finished with exit code 0
```

You can do a similar thing with a specialized class, but I think the lambda is more concise and essentially the same.

Answer (score 0):

For a one-liner you could also try this:

```
os.environ.get(VAR_NAME, DEFAULT_FOR_TEST_ARG)
```